# log in to Facebook button from a chrome extension

Tags: facebook, google-chrome

I have a chrome extension hosted on Google servers.
I am trying to add an option to login with FB on my extension (using parse.com js sdk to do so)

Seems to work fine , until the following message pops up from FB :

- Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or
  more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must
  match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a
  subdomain of one of the App's domains.

I came to realize that the issue is the site URL that i've entered in the app configurations on FB.

What URL do i need to enter in this case ? Nothing seems to work.
I don't really have a site , but a simply extension hosted on google .

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Comment: not directly.i've created a website just for the purpose of the FB login and directing users to this site from the ext.